# Using ADXL3xx with Arduino

Tags: arduino, accelerometer, sensors, serial-communication, atmega

I used the arduino example code for the adxl3xx accelerometer. I have not yet connected the analog pins so my arduino should give me 0 value yet the value my arduino prints varies between 700-1023. Why is that? I also tried the AnalogInOutSerial example and the result is the same.

Comment: probably just static around the pin. you should get more stable value once you complete the circuit

Comment: When i completed the circuit I got the same values.

Comment: That is a bit strange. Do you have a simple sensor you test the same analog pin ? (e.g. a potentiometer, flex sensor, pressure sensor?) Can you also try a different analog pin ?

Comment: Using different pin worked. If instead of A0, A1 and A2 pins I connect the pins to A3, A2 and A1 pins it works. I dont understand why.